# detect dulpicate elements in multi column arraylist in android/java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I have an array list structure like this:

```
ArrayList<Arraylisttableitem> tablestatuslist = new ArrayList<Arraylisttableitem>();
```

The model class for this array list is mentioned below:

```
public class Arraylisttableitem {

    String total, noofcustomer, firstname, tab_name, balance, time;

    public Arraylisttableitem(String total, String noofcustomer,
            String firstname, String tab_name, String balance, String time) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.total = total;
        this.noofcustomer = noofcustomer;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.tab_name = tab_name;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getNoofcustomer() {
        return noofcustomer;
    }

    public void setNoofcustomer(String noofcustomer) {
        this.noofcustomer = noofcustomer;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getTab_name() {
        return tab_name;
    }

    public void setTab_name(String tab_name) {
        this.tab_name = tab_name;
    }

    public String getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(String balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

In the element named tab_name I may have duplicate elements. I want to identify the duplicated element and add all the duplicate values. For example, tab_num 10 has balance 5, and tab_num 10 has balance 10. What I want is tab_nam 10 should appear once and balance should be 15 without any duplicate value in the list.

How can this be solved?

I don't know what to write inside this..

```
for(Arraylisttableitem itemlist : tablestatuslist)
                    {
                        
                    }
```

My JSON has duplicate values, so my arraylist supportd duplicate values.

Comment: Why not handle this case when you're adding objects to the arraylist, rather than removing the duplicates later on ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma this would slow down the entire operation everytime data is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add values then better keep the field types as int rather than string. However in your case you could do like

```
Map<String, Arraylisttableitem> map = new HashMap<String, Arraylisttableitem>();
for(Arraylisttableitem item : tableStatusList){
    Arraylisttableitem prevItem = map.get(item.getTab_name());
    if(prevItem != null){
        prevItem.setTotal(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(item.getTotal()) + Integer.parseInt(prevItem.getTotal())));
        prevItem.setBalance(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(item.getBalance()) + Integer.parseInt(prevItem.getBalance())));
        prevItem.setNoofcustomer(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(item.getNoofcustomer()) + Integer.parseInt(prevItem.getNoofcustomer())));
        prevItem.setTime(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(item.getTime()) + Integer.parseInt(prevItem.getTime())));
        map.put(item.getTab_name(), prevItem);
    } else {
        map.put(item.getTab_name(), item);
    }
}       
tableStatusList = new ArrayList<Arraylisttableitem>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change from a List to a Set as sets do not allow duplicate values.
- In Arraylisttableitem override methods **hashCode** and *equals**

Comment: i have to support duplicate value.

Comment: This does not add the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html), for each each item. When you [put](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) an item to the map, it will return you the old item that previously been stored there. So this is the place where you can marge the two.